# how to change icons using themes?

Tags: c#, winforms, themes

I have to implement multiple theme support throughout my windows form application. I want to use different icons for different themes, and make the icon set dependent on the theme a user chooses. Is there a way to do this in a theme file rather than specifying the icons in the code.

Comment: Resource Files? Resource Assemblies?

Comment: Have you seen [this: ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18603/Advanced-UxTheme-wrapper); may get you started